# Valid reason to prove the dis-associativity of ($\mathbb R, -)$.

Tags: group-theory, associativity, magma

Is this a valid proof?
Let $a,b,c$ $\in$ $(\mathbb R, -)$. We want to prove that $(\mathbb R, -)$ does not have an associative property. Assume that it is associative such that: $a-(b-c) = (a-b)-c$.

---

$a-(b-c) = (a-b)-c$
$\Rightarrow$
$a+c=(a-b)+(b-c)$
$\Rightarrow$
$c+a=(a-b)+(b-c)$
So $c=a-b$ and $a=b-c.$
But $c=a-b$ is equal to $a=c+b$, which is a contradiction to the previous statement.

Hence $(\mathbb R, -)$ does not have an associative property.

Comment: The implication after the 'So' is not correct. So, the argument doesn't constitute a proof. Note that you can show that a general property is false by just giving a counterexample. Take, for instance, $a=b=c=1$. Then $a-(b-c)=1$ while $(a-b)-c=-1$.

Comment: To show that something does not *always* happen, it is sufficient to exhibit a single instance in which it does not occur. You don't need to show that $(a-b)-c$ is *never* equal to $a-(b-c)$. You just need to exhibit a single instance of specific values of $a,b,c$ for which $(a-b)-c\neq a-(b-c)$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $c+a=(a-b)+(b-c)$ so $c=a-b$ and $a=b-c.$

No, that is wrong. You know that $1+3 = 2+2$, right? But does it mean that $1=2$ and $3=2$?

The real solution is simple. Take $a=b=c=1$ and evaluate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\begin{align} (1-1)-1&=0-1 \\ &=-1 \\ &\neq 1 \\ &=1-0 \\ &=1-(1-1),\end{align}$$ so $(1-1)-1\neq 1-(1-1)$. Thus $(\Bbb R, -)$ is not associative.